# SQL "Alter Table" for foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

So I'm learning some SQL as a bit of a side project since my SQL sucks. I have the following table I created:

```
CREATE TABLE deliveries (
  pid INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES person_lives_at,
  );
```

I want to alter it to be a table like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE deliveries (
  pid INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES employee,
  );
```

How can I achieve that? I'm using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: If the table is empty, just drop it and recreate it.

Comment: The table is not empty unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you created an FK constraint without a name, oracle assigned a system-generated name to the constraint like SYS_xxxxxx.  To find the constraint name:

```
select constraint_name from all_Constraints
where table_name = 'DELIVERIES'
```

In  my test case, it returned "SYS_C0016779".  I then drop the constraint:

```
alter table deliveries drop constraint SYS_C0016779
```

Then add the new constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE deliveries
ADD CONSTRAINT PID_EMP_FK -- or whatever you want to call it.
   FOREIGN KEY (pid)
   REFERENCES employee(pid); -- or whatever the name of the column is
```

Comment: @BryanE - Do you understand why you must drop the original constraint, and it is not sufficient to just add the new one? (Hint: It is legal, and sometimes it may even make sense, for a column in a table to be a foreign key TWICE, referencing the primary keys of two different tables - or even two different unique columns in the same table! BOTH foreign key constraints would have to be satisfied in that case.)

Comment: Yes, I do understand that. You can't have the same thing being used as a foreign key for two references. Thanks!